# How to incremental update Java EE web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, deployment

I have a typical web application deployed in Tomcat.  The requirement is to provide **incremental update** way instead of **full-package** delivery (a war file) when update the application.

For example, once I finish a bug fix which changed a jar file, an XML file and jpg file. I call these 3 files as a patch. I am supposed to deliver the patch file. Even when customers want to rollback to original version, I have to provider a way to rollback the patch.
All the process is supposed to automatically.

From my perspective, the requirement doesn’t make sense. full-package delivery is easy and reliable way to update a web application, I don’t want to introduce complex and error-prone way to update.

Do you have idea to implement incremental update requirement? Thanks!

Comment: Your perspective is correct. Incremental update is just about impossible to keep track of and support. You wind up with a customer with an app that's of no particular version, and no good way to roll back either. My suggestion - don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy the .war or .ear, the application server usually unpack it into an internal directory. You can change files in this directory directly, with a finer granularity. However, for changes to take effect consistently, you will need to restart the server.

Your perspective is indeed fully correct. Nowadays, sizes of files don't play a significant role, I don't see the problem with whole updates.  Why isn't the customer happy with whole updates?

Note: If what he wants is *dynamic* updates, i.e. without restarting the server, then this is anyway a complete different problem, and mostly impossible for production systems in java (but doable during development, with solutions like JRebel).

Comment: There's another product based on JRebel, but meant for updating the application in live environment, called LiveRebel. That can do hot updates too and automate the rollouts for multiple nodes, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Java Program that uses Delta-Sync protocol i.e. Only those files need to uploaded which are updated. If you have used Dropbox then you will understand pretty well.
Dropbox uses Delta-Sync protocol to update file and sync data.

Either way for time being you can use Dropbox by installing on your client (mapping to server's WAR folder) and your local machine and share that folder. Then whenever you change the files in your local machine it will automatically upload and sync those CHANGED (PATCH) files to your client's machine.

Comment: This is an extraordinarily bad idea. Totally unsupportable. As I mentioned in my previous comment, the only sane answer is to not do this at all.